# Database choice for 30000 x 5000 Big table, each item may have 100M in size

Tags: database

I have a 30000 x 5000 big table, and each item in the table may have 100M (even more) in size, can anyone give me some advice to choose a database?

Comment: Without knowing how you intend to use that data, there's no telling. One extreme is, if you never access it, you don't need a database at all (you don't even need the data...). Another extreme is full-text searching and continuous random-access (read/write) of the content.

Comment: You do realize, that assuming most items are 100M, you're talking about 13 PETAbytes of data, or about 14,305 Terabytes. Are you sure you need this data?

Comment: Some items may have 100M, and some items may have 0K. My expression is not clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

13 Petabytes of data? I'm impressed.

Without knowing how you're going to query the database it is hard to say what would work, but a standard filesystem can handle 100-megabyte objects, duplicate objects can be handled with hard or soft links, 'sparse' entries just not populated, and 30,000 directories in a directory should be fine in ext3 with htree turned on. (`tune2fs` option `dir_index`.)

But perhaps your SAN vendor will have some strong opinions about what sorts of systems work well when you've scaled to 13 Petabytes -- I suggest talking with your system vendor's sales engineers, the sales engineers I have known have been scary good.

Comment: Some items may have 100M, and some items may have 0K. My expression is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really serious about this, your best bet is [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). Can't help you much more though.

Comment: "The largest production cluster has over 100 TB of data in over 150 machines." I hope it can scale 130 times larger.. :)